# Why does the ordering of and or with an and filter matter in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the below query to Elasticsearch 2.3.1:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                    "query": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "my search",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "fields": ["field1^6", "field2", "field3^2", "field4"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "zero_terms_query": "all"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "or": [{
                    "term": {
                        "pickup": true
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "local_delivery": true
                    }
                }],
                "and": [{
                    "term": {
                        "field5": true
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "field6": "my_value"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query returns 11K results. If I switch the ordering of the or and the and to be the below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                    "query": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "my search",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "fields": ["field1^6", "field2", "field3^2", "field4"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "zero_terms_query": "all"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": [{
                    "term": {
                        "field5": true
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "field6": "my_value"
                    }
                }],
                "or": [{
                    "term": {
                        "pickup": true
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "local_delivery": true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now suddenly only have 675 results.

Shouldn't these queries be the exact same? In essence I want to filter my query to have field5 as true and field6 as my_value. But I also want either of pickup or local_delivery to be true, so:

```
(field5 == true && field6 == "my_value" || (pickup == true || local_delivery == true))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a bool query fixes this problem:

```
"filter": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "term": {
                "pickup": true
            }
        }, {
            "term": {
                "local_delivery": true
            }
        }],
        "must": [{
            "term": {
                "field5": true
            }
        }, {
            "term": {
                "field6": "my_value"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```